# Как изменить статус кнопки Disabled нa normal с помощью переменой

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет в общем хочу чтобы при значении p >= 0  статус кнопки был normal, а при p < 0 был disabled
Вот код

```
from tkinter import *  
   
a = 0
b = 0
p = 10
c = a + b
s = "disabled"
if p > 9:
    s = "normal"
if p < 6:
    s = "disabled"
def clicked():  
    global a, p, s
    a += 1
    c = a + b
    p -= 1
    lbl.configure(text=(f"сила{a}" ) ) 
    lbl2.configure(text=(f"урон{c}" ) )  
    lbl3.configure(text=(f"балы{p}" ) )  
def clicked1():  
    global b,  p,  s
    b += 1
    c = a + b
    p -= 1
        
    lbl1.configure(text=(f"мастерство {b}" ) ) 
    lbl2.configure(text=(f"урон {c}" ) )  
    lbl3.configure(text=(f"Clicks {p}" ) )  
    

window = Tk()  
lbl = Label(window, text=(f"сила {a}" ) ) 
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)  

lbl1 = Label(window, text=(f"мастерство {b}" ) ) 
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=1)  

lbl2 = Label(window, text=(f"урон {c}" ) ) 
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=2)  


lbl3 = Label(window, text=(f"балы {p}" ) ) 
lbl3.grid(column=0, row=3)  

btn = Button(window, text="+", command=clicked, state=[s])  
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)  

btn1 = Button(window, text="+", command=clicked1,state=["normal"])
btn1.grid(column=1, row=1)  

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: После изменения p проверяете условие и меняете состояние кнопки. Это нужно делать в функциях, а не при запуске программы.

Comment: То есть добавить условие в саму функцию

Comment: То есть поместить условие в отдельную функцию (не забыть в нее же добавить изменение состояния кнопки), эту функцию вызывать после изменения p.

Comment: @insolor Можете показать ето в виде кода, я понимаю что от меня требуется но мой уровень знания языка довольно низок, так что я не могу правильно ето реализовать, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Если вы попытаетесь, то у вас получится. Мне неинтересно этим вопросом заниматься, но возможно кто-то другой добавит ответ.

Comment: Спасибо у меня всё получилось